# Difference of complexity between double nested for loops? (Java)

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, time

What's the difference in terms of performance and complexity between these two nested for loops?

```
for(int i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

and :

```
for(int i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < l.length; j++) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first loop is about twice as fast as the second one, but in terms of the asymptotic time complexity they are the same:

```
O(N^2)
```

You can think anout it graphically: imagine a square with N units on each side. The second loop visits all unit squares;

```
######
######
######
######
######
######
```

the first loop visits the points that belong to a triangle covering half the square:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
######
```

Answer (score 3):

Both loops have the same assimptotic behaviour - O(n**2)

1. 1st loop: `1 + 2 + ... + n = n(n+1)/2 = n*n/2 + n/2 -> O(n**2)`
2. 2nd loop: `n*n -> O(n**2)`

So 2nd loop is near as twice as slow than the 1st loop, while the assimptotic is the same